# Comment rendre la nuance de « set [of entries] » en français, dans un logiciel ?

Tags: traduction, informatique

Le mot « *set* » en anglais est utilisé dans un grand nombre de contextes et avec des traductions toutes très différentes en français.

Je cherche à localiser en français une application d'apprentissage de langues qui fait usage du mot « *set(s)* » pour désigner des groupes d'entrées qui peuvent être créés, chargés ou étudiés ensemble (« *create a set* », « *browse other people's sets* » etc).

Dans le cas où le mot se réfère à un groupe d'objets (concrets ou figurés), je crois que la traduction standard serait « ensemble » (voire « groupe »), néanmoins la connotation résultante n'est pas très satisfaisante ici (assez peu naturelle et ambigüe) : là où tout utilisateur de logiciel anglophone comprend aisément « *browse available sets* », je ne suis pas sûr que l'usage de « parcourir les ensembles » parlerait à un francophone.

L'autre option serait d'utiliser le mot « jeu », au sens de « jeu de fiches » (« créer un nouveau jeu »...), mais c'est encore plus ambigu dans une interface, compte tenu de la connotation « jeu vidéo », infiniment plus courante.

Dans les deux cas, la longueur du mot est un facteur limitant (utiliser « jeu de fiches » ou « ensemble de questions » partout où le mot « *set* » apparait, alourdirait considérablement l'interface).

**Est-ce qu'il existe un terme français qui rendrait mieux ce sens du mot « *set* » ? Serait-il même envisageable d'utiliser le mot « set » tel quel en français (en étant compris par le plus grand nombre, à défaut de se faire des amis à l'Académie) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Très souvent, quand un mot veut tout dire et rien dire, c'est qu'il est inutile, et qu'il peut être purement et simplement supprimé de la phrase : *the set of books* -> *the books*. (et oui même en anglais ça marche).

En informatique c'est un peu différent, car l'informatique a besoin de mots clefs, de séparateurs ; mettre *set of* partout dans les textes humains est, je pense, une dérive de ça.

Aussi, plutôt que de désigner la forme groupée, j'essaierais de désigner le groupe formé (hein).

*Panier* est très utilisé dans le commerce électronique. C'est pas mal, même si c'est très commun, parce qu'il donne aussi l'image... c'est quand même mieux que *ensemble de commissions*.

Pour **désigner des groupes d'entrées qui peuvent être créés, chargés ou étudiés ensemble** pour l'apprentissage de langues, vous pourriez mettre *leçon*, mais c'est un mot qui fait un peu vieux. Il y a le mot *cours*, un peu mieux du point de vue de la mode.

*Module*, aussi. *Consultez les modules*, ça fait quand même chou. Et j'ai vu aussi *Unité interactive*... *Parcourez les unités interactives* :-)

Et enfin le mot encore plus passe partout que le mot set : *ressources*. Remplacer un mot passe partout par un autre encore plus inutile, c'est ça, l'intelligence !

Comment: +1  Pour le point de vue plus général sur la question.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le contexte, une *bibliothèque* pourrait être une traduction acceptable. Ou une *collection*.

Dans les deux cas, tu as bien la notion d'*ensemble*, avec la nuance que cet *ensemble* peut être ordonné, quel qu'en soit l'ordre.

Comment: Ensemble n'implique certainement pas la notion d'ordre pour moi.

Comment: Effectivement, ça n'est d'ailleurs pas ce que je sous-entendais.
Par contre, dans _set_, et à la vue du contexte, on peut imaginer que la notion d'ordre soit pertinente. Elle est soutendue par _bibliothèque_ ou _collection_, ne serait-ce que dans la sélection qui a permis de la rassembler.
Ça semble coller avec la demande de traduction initiale.

Comment: L'ordre n'est pas spécialement pertinent (c'est d'ailleurs une des qualités d'un "set" en mathématiques). Mais *bibliothèque* est une suggestion intéressante. J'ai juste peur que ce ne soit un peu trop lourd pour un élément d'interface récurrent... Mais je crois que c'est un problème avec la langue française en général.

Comment: Mathématiquement/informatiquement, un ensemble est différent d'une bibliothèque (indexée, éléments complexes) et d'une collection(multiples occurences d'un même objet possible). Si l'ont souhaite être rigoureux, ces deux termes sont donc inappropriés. la notion d'ordre est quant à elle liée au terme "liste". Pour appuyer ceci, il est intéressant de voir l'usage des termes "list", "set" et "collection" dans le langage Java : http://fmora.developpez.com/tutoriel/java/collections/introduction/#

Comment: Notons que la question, à l'origine, portait sur la traduction du terme _set_. Par ailleurs, le contexte n'est pas forcément mathématique ou informatique, @Dave parle d'apprentissage des langues. Je continue à penser que selon le contexte, _bibliothèque_ ou _collection_ sont des traductions acceptables.

Answer (score 1):

Selon la représentation graphique de ces *sets*, un terme valable pourrait être *liste*. C'est court, véhicule l'idée de pouvoir ajouter des éléments, et de pouvoir naviguer d'un élément à un autre.

J'éviterais l'utilisation du terme anglais, sauf si c'est dans le cadre d'un logiciel suffisamment spécialisé et que le mot *set* est connu pour faire partie du jargon de la majorité des utilisateurs.

Answer (score 1):

Le terme "sets" utilisé dans un contexte "logiciel" en anglais fait souvent référence à une structure mathématique bien connue (avec ou sans relation d'ordre). Le terme français approprié est, à mon avis, "ensemble" même pour une utilisation moins connotée mathématiquement comme "data set".

Comment: Je lis les autres réponses et comme je n'ai pas assez de réputation je me contente de commenter la mienne ... le mot ensemble veut dire quelque chose en informatique. Ce n'est pas un mot passe partout et il n'est pas vague. En dehors du sens mathématique il recouvre aussi un codage particulier. Pour plus d'info cherchez théorie des ensembles dans votre moteur de recherche préféré.

Answer (score 0):

Si je comprends bien le contexte, « répertoire » pourrait convenir. Mon reproche à « ensemble », c'est qu'il est trop vague, pas qu'il ne serait pas compris.  Si toutes les entrées sont des mots ou des phrases à traduire, « lexique » serait aussi un candidat, mais ce terme a le problème opposé, il est trop spécifique.